# How do I include the git branch name with setuptools-scm?

Tags: git, version-control, setuptools, setuptools-scm

By default, `setuptools_scm` (when using git) produces version numbers such as:

`mytool-1.2.3.dev42+ba98765.d19700101`

I would like to include the branch name.  I'm not set on the exact form, but maybe like this:

`mytool-1.2.3.dev42+ba98765.branchname.d19700101`

I found a [pull request](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/pull/240) with the name *add support for branch name based testing*, but it has no description or documentation.  I'm not 100% sure if it does what I'm looking for.  What options do I add to the `[tool.setuptools_scm]` section in my `pyproject.toml` to include branch information in the `setuptools_scm`-generated version?

Comment: You might have your own use for branch names, but in practice, branch names are useless because they don't specify a particular commit (or rather, they do, but it *changes* over time). A commit hash ID or the output from `git describe` *does* specify a particular commit, and is therefore useful (forever); you should try to use that.

Comment: @torek I want to include both.  I don't agree with the idea that branch names are useless. I might have different feature branches, and when testing their functionality and performance, it's quite useful for human readability if in logfiles I include not only the commit ID, but also the branch name.  Adding this information to the version is a straightforward way of keeping track of what approach is being tested. I've used my own implementation for years, but am now transitioning to setuptools-scm and would like to retain this information.